# What is the "pub" theme?

Tags: themes, homepage, theme-options, blog

I've been trying to mimic the kinds of websites/blogs that mathematicians have with WordPress and typically their theme is "pub"--it shows up in their style.css, "https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/themes/pub/rubric/style.css".

I looked it up on https://wordpress.org/themes/ but couldn't find a result. Does this theme even exist? Apologies if this question elementary. And another question that might relate to the pub theme--this one is a little bit more specific--how do I mimic the wide and long blog posts that appear on https://almostsure.wordpress.com/ ?

Comment: You would need to ask someone who uses it. It could be a paid theme, a bespoke theme, or no longer available.

Comment: I answered your first question, and have ignored the second, we have a 1 question per question policy on the site, so ask separate questions as a new question. However, I'm pretty sure that last question is offtopic as it's a styling question, it's super wide because that's how that theme is built. I would recommend against super wide text though as it's innaccessible and makes reading difficult. You want too aim for a max of 40-60 characters per line for easy reading

Answer (score 2):

There is no `pub` theme, that's a quirk of how WordPress.com the premium 3rd party service ran by Automattic is internally structured. It's non-standard.

To be more specific WP.com doesn't use the normal theme folder structure, and instead of searching `wp-content/themes` for theme folders, it searches `wp-content/themes/pub` and several others for themes, but mostly `pub`.

This is done purely to keep all the public themes together and was done a very long time ago as a result of technical decisions made early on. Specifically, the `pub` folder is an SVN checkout of a shared theme folder repo containing lots of themes. To avoid putting internal things in a publicly visible SVN repository, somebody came up with the subfolder system. Now they're stuck with it for historical reasons.

I would not recommend doing this on your own site, or using the structure of WP.com as an example of best practices. WP.com is an enormous multisite install ( multi-network too ), with a lot of obscure historical changes, and user/site counts in the hundreds of millions and more. Normal rules don't apply here, nor do normal hosting structures ( for example wp.com is hosted across multiple data centres ).

If you want more details on that, you'll need to speak with someone who works at Automattic.